# breadcrumb path: retrieve data for everything under a path

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I have a few paths that look as follows on my application, all under a breadcrumb path.

```
/class/:slug
/class/:slug/student/:_id
/class/:slug/teacher/:_id
```

However, this tends to lead to redundancy because I have to constantly look up the class by slug before querying

```
this.route('Class.teacher', {
  path: '/class/:slug/teacher/:_id',
  waitOn: function() {
    return Meteor.subscribe('teachers');
  },
  data: function() {
    var classId = Classes.findOne({ slug: this.params.slug })._id;
    if(!classId) {
      throw new Meteor.Error(404, 'That class does not exist');
    }

    return Teacher.findOne(
      { _id: this.params._id, classIds: classId }
    );
  }
})
```

The problem is the amount of redundancy this appears to induce, as I start most of my routes with finding the class.

Is there a way to perform some sort of manipulation on the `/class/:slug` route? I was thinking something like this:

```
Router.route('/class/:slug/*', {
  waitOn: function() {
    return Meteor.subscribe('classes', this.params.slug);
  },
  onBeforeAction: function() {
    var class = Classes.findOne(this.params.slug);
    if(!class) {
      throw new Meteor.Error(404, "Class not found");
      this.stop();
    }
    this.next();
  }
});
```

However, this doesn't work. What is the proper way to handle breadcrumb paths in this way?

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use

```
Router.onBeforeAction(function(req, res, next){
    // find class here
    // req.params.slug Not sure about this
    next()
}, { only: ['class'] });
```

Just an idea though.